# Did it install anything?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, virus, steam

i was on steam today and somebody sent me a friend request so i accepted it 1 hour later the guy (bot) wanted to trade with me he sent me a link I didn’t read the link so I clicked on it I thought the link was something like imgur it downloaded something the Icon of the program was the windows 10 image icon I closed chrome and cancelled the download before it finished downloading.
After that I opened chrome again and clicked the three dots on the top right then clicked on downloads, the “windows image icon” turned out to be a program but it was cancelled and not downloaded, so my question is did it install anything? Because I’m so scared right now my pc is worth 2k and I have a lot things on it that I don’t want to lose.
Any answer would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: No, if you canceled the download how would it install? But if you're scared about your data I suggest you do frequent backups. Other than that, worse case scenario, the OS and programs can be reinstalled anytime.

Comment: like the sleepy penguin states, it got cancelled but if you want to be sure, use an AV, antimalware just to be sure but ....

Use a usb or an ext hard drive and make a backup of everything you need especially when you say you dont wanna lose it. Hell, use onedrive or google drive if you really have to...make a backup

Answer (score 0):

It probably didn't install anything - you closed your browser before it finished downloading, so the temporary file Chrome makes for the downloaded file would be deleted.

If you really want to be sure, download reliable antivirus software such as [AVG](https://www.avg.com) or [Bitdefender](https://www.bitdefender.co.uk/) and run a scan.